# Django queryset to string does not return the string in a test

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-tests

I'm trying to write a unit test for this model:

```py
ADMIN = 1
FULL_USER = 2
LIMITED_USER = 3

class Role(models.Model):
  """
  The class stores the model to store the different role which will be used to assign permissions
  to the users.
  """
  ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (ADMIN, 'admin'),
        (FULL_USER, 'full_user'),
        (LIMITED_USER, 'limited_user')
  )

  id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField('name', max_length=30)

  def __str__(self):
    """String for representing the Model object."""
    if self.name:
      return self.name
    return self.id
```

So I wrote this test:

```py
from example.models import Role
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class RoleModel(APITestCase):

    fixtures = ["initial_data/role.json"]

    def test_get_admin_role(self):
        role = Role.objects.filter(id=1)
        self.assertEqual(str(role), 'admin')
```

But I'm not able to understand why it fails with this:

```
AssertionError: '<QuerySet [<Role: admin>]>' != 'admin'
- <QuerySet [<Role: admin>]>
+ admin
```

I have read similar questions on how to get the string of the queryset and it should be the one defined in `__str__`. but I don't know why it is surrounded by `<QuerySet [<Role: HERE_IS_MY_STRING]>` if I'm asking for the string representation of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `role` is a `QuerySet` (a collection) of `Role`s. A collection can contain, zero, one, or more `Role`s. A collection is *not* the same as an object.

You can obtain a `Role` *object* with [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get):

```
def test_get_admin_role(self):
    role = Role.objects.get(id=1)
    self.assertEqual(str(role), 'admin')
```

Note that a `__str__` object should always return a `str`ing, not an `int` for example. In the `__str__` method, you thus should call `str(…)` on the `.id`:

```
def __str__(self):
    """String for representing the Model object."""
    if self.name:
        return self.name
    return str(self.id)
```